# How to change the concurrent build path separator in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

When marking a job as able to run concurrently on the same node, Jenkins will append a @X (where X is the number of the concurrent build) to the normal workspace directory to get a new, unique workspace directory.  Normally, this is all fine and good, but we've encountered a couple tools that cannot handle a @ in the path name even though the operating system can.

Is there some way to change the @ character to something else?  Say maybe a double underscore (__) or something?

Answer (score 2):

This thread may help:
http://jenkins.361315.n4.nabble.com/Concurrent-executions-and-workspace-names-td4631221.html

...
 I can do this with a system property.  I believe -Dhudson.slaves.WorkspaceList="=" will do the trick.

Using https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Throttle+Concurrent+Builds+Plugin 
The Throttle Concurrent Builds plugin might also help.

Answer (score 2):

As I am not allowed to comment Lees answer here is my modified answer his

use `-Dhudson.slaves.WorkspaceList==`

otherwise it will build the project in [JENKINS]/workspace/myProject"="2

Comment: Hello. If you're not allowed to comment, you should build up your reputation. Posting comments as answers brings the quality of the site down. Happy coding!